# Wrapped property with @propertyWrapper won't return wrapped type

Tags: swift5

In this simplified example, I make a propertyWrapper of an UInt to hold a Natural Number (an Integer > 0). My own example uses a more complex filter but this shows the issue. Rather than find a workaround, the point of the question is to shed light on the confusing (to me) error.

Assigning it to a simple UInt brings the error message listed.

Using its wrappedValue property as in the following line works fine. But surely the whole point of the wrapping is to be able to treat it as an UInt as returned by the get?

The error "cannot assign value of type 'NonZero' to type 'UInt" appears to undermine the whole point of the wrapper type. What am I misunderstanding?
Xcode 11.0

```
import Foundation

@propertyWrapper
struct NonZero {
      private let myNumber : UInt

    init(n : UInt)
    {
     if ( n == 0){fatalError(" cannot be 0")}
        myNumber = n
    }
   var wrappedValue: UInt {
    get { return myNumber }
    }
}


struct Nums {

    var num :UInt

    init( nz:  NonZero){
        num = nz                //error message "cannot assign value of type 'NonZero' to type 'UInt"
        num = nz.wrappedValue   //no error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how property wrappers work. The code:

```
init(nz: NonZero)
```

declares `nz` to have the type `NonZero` – which is just the `struct` defined earlier, `NonZero` here is not being used as a wrapped property.

A wrapped property is used as an *attribute* on a property declaration, for example:

```
@NonZero var num : UInt = 1
```

[Putting that in the code requires changing the parameter label of `NonZero`'s `init` to be changed to `wrappedValue`, e.g.:

```
init(wrappedValue : Uint) { ... wrappedValue ... }
```

]

You could write the `init` of `struct Nums` as:

```
init(nz: UInt)
{
   num = nz // ok *after* you add a `set` to `NonZero`, will `fatalError` if `nz` is zero
   let unwrapped : UInt = num // ok
   print(unwrapped) // so you see it worked
}
```

Keep exploring! You might find [SE-0259 Property Wrappers](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md#restrictions-on-the-use-of-property-wrappers) (Apple) and [Swift Property Wrappers](https://nshipster.com/propertywrapper/) (NSHipster) useful.

HTH